# Xampp mysql shutdown unexpectedly after update

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I have a big problem with xampp mysql. Yesterday accept a windows update in the server, and while update is complete, I can't start the mysql.

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 32M, instances = 1, chunk size = 32M
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 47054; transaction id 9
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210107 14:05:56
2021-01-07 14:05:56 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I try backup the mysql\data folder, clear all, and try delete the ibtmp1 file, not work, and I try change the port, isn't work.

I look, this log write, the ibtmp1 file is 12 Mb, but my ibtmp1 file is 70 Mb for me.

Comment: this log shows no errors and is a quite normal functioning mysql server, so you have to show us the actual errors

Comment: It might help if you post the xampp version, windows version, what exactly has been updated.